# I need Plugin Audio for flutter work for both android, iOS

Tags: url, flutter

I need a Plugin Audio for flutter that work for both android, iOS

also, if it's support an option to download an audio from url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best i could find that works best for you situation is the [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) package.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more precise on what you exactly need. There are some plugins for Flutter dealing with audio, e.g. [AudioPlayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers).